# Deleting an Outlook Message via the EWS API?

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in and trying to delete a message in a via the EWS API (soap envelopes).
Following the docs [DeleteItem Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/deleteitem-operation) unfortunately does not work for me.
I'm making an **mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync()** request with the follwing request envelope.
All my other EWS Request are working just fine, only this request always fails with an  **ErrorInvalidRequest** response. I've googled and searched stackoverflow already quite a lot with no success. Unfortunately I have to use EWS to do this. Also a soft delete (moving to trash) works.

Request:

```
request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
        '        xmlns:t="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"> ' +
        '   <soap:Body> ' +
        '       <DeleteItem DeleteType="HardDelete" xmlns="https://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">' +
        '           <ItemIds> ' +
        '               <t:ItemId Id="' + item_id + '/> ' +
        '           </ItemIds> ' +
        '       </DeleteItem> ' +
        '   </soap:Body> ' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';
```

Response:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution (Edit):**
The answer from Glen Scales below works perfectly.
Just moving the Item to a purges folder, in my case the 'recoverableitemspurges' folder, which is not visible for the user and hence equal to a hard delete
For reference, all the deletedItem folders:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/deleting-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange#find-out-more-about-deleting-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

makeEWSRequestAsync can only be used on a subset of EWS operations these are listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions (under ReadWriteMailbox permission). DeleteItems is not allowed, moveitems is so you could try just moving the Message to the Purges folders which would be equal to a Hard Delete.